# Parse JSON document based on predefined JSON mapping document in Java

Tags: java, json, algorithm, design-patterns, jsonparser

I want to get some idea if there is any **library in Java** that I can use to **filter** a **JSON document based on a predefined JSON mapping document**, or only way to achieve this is to write custom java code.

If it's required to write Java custom code what type of **design pattern or data structure** I should follow. Any advice will be very much appreciated.

Example -

**Input JSON document -**

```
{
  "basicInfo": {
    "name": "name",
    "age": "25",
    "address": "address"
  },
  "education": [
    {
      "ug": {
        "unversity": "university",
        "major": [
          "cs",
          "ds"
        ],
        "year": "2012"
      },
      "pg": {
        "unversity": "university",
        "major": [
          "cs",
          "ds"
        ],
        "year": "2015"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**Predefined JSON mapping document (Can be defined in any JSON format, below is one such example that I have created) -**

```
{
    "definitions": {
      "basicInfo": {
        "maxOccurance": "1",
        "fields": [
          {
            "key": "name",
            "type": "S",
            "lenght": "50",
            "usage": "M",
            "maxOccurrance": "1"
          },
          {
            "key": "age",
            "type": "S",
            "lenght": "3",
            "usage": "O",
            "maxOccurrance": "1"
          }
        ]
      },
      "education": {
        "maxOccurance": "10",
        "fields": [
          {
            "pg": {
              "maxOccurance": "1",
              "fields": [
                {
                  "key": "university",
                  "type": "S",
                  "lenght": "50",
                  "usage": "M",
                  "maxOccurrance": "1"
                },
                {
                  "key": "major",
                  "type": "S",
                  "lenght": "3",
                  "usage": "O",
                  "maxOccurrance": "1"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
```

**Expected output JSON document**

```
{
    "basicInfo": {
      "name": "name",
      "age": "25"
    },
    "education": [
      {
        "pg": {
          "unversity": "university",
          "major": "cs"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: IDEs like Visual Studio support generating classes when we `paste JSON string`, to make this kind of work easier. Check if any of the Java IDEs support that as well.

Comment: you could check out these https://github.com/joelittlejohn/jsonschema2pojo, https://json2csharp.com/json-to-pojo

Comment: @AnandSowmithiran Thank you for the information, what exactly I am looking for is a way to filter a JSON document based on a predefined JSON spec sheet / JSON mapping document. So is there a readymade utility that will read the JSON spec document and filter the input JSON document and produce a output JSON document as mentioned in the example.

Comment: ok, understood. check if this library named [jolt](https://github.com/bazaarvoice/jolt#jolt) meets your requirement.

Comment: Yes, going through the document and looks like it's going to be useful for the requirement. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The request is for a way to filter a JSON document based on a predefined JSON spec sheet / JSON mapping document. The [jolt](https://github.com/bazaarvoice/jolt#jolt) library would likely be able to meet this requirement.